# Jenkins, build errors when retrieving code for Git repo

Tags: git, jenkins

I have Jenkins installed on a Redhat Linux box.

I have installed all the git plugins in Jenkins.

I have installed Git on the server via `yum install git`.  It looks like the executable is located in `/usr/bin/git` (Jenkins won't recognize `git.exe`).

We have an internal Git repo via TeamForge. (I connected to the a github repo successfully, just having an issue with our company Git repo).

Can anyone help me connect to the internal Git repo? The error log looks like:

```
Building in workspace /root/.jenkins/jobs/test/workspace
/usr/bin/git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
/usr/bin/git config remote.origin.url git clone ssh://b002653@teamforge.server:29418/cdn_scdn # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git clone ssh://b002653@teamforge.server:29418/cdn_macys_scdn
/usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
/usr/bin/git fetch --tags --progress git clone ssh://b002653@teamforge.server:29418/cdn_scdn +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git clone ssh://b002653@teamforge.server:29418/cdn_macys_scdn
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:735)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:983)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1016)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:485)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1282)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:610)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:532)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1744)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:374)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "/usr/bin/git fetch --tags --progress git clone ssh://b002653@teamforge.server:29418/cdn_macys_scdn +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: I don't handle protocol 'git clone ssh'

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1591)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1379)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:86)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:324)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:733)
    ... 11 more
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have pasted `git clone ssh://b002653@teamforge.server:29418/...` into your checkout job instead of `ssh://b002653@teamforge.server:29418/...`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you give the correct **Path to Git executable** 
in my case it was like bellow [image]
and the other mistake can see that you are providing **git clone** along with your url
as you can see in the console it says `fatal: I don't handle protocol 'git clone ssh'`

so you need to provide `ssh://b002653@teamforge.server:29418/cdn_scdn`
[image]

I hope it will do the job